# Axios call always ending in then() callback

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I am calling this Vuex action that is triggering Axios request that is put in the try/catch block.

I am calling this:

```
this.$store
  .dispatch('api/get', { url: url })
  .then(data => { console.log(data) })
  .catch(error => { console.log(error) })
```

The Vuex action

```
async get({ commit }, payload) {
  try {
    let response = await this.$axios.get(payload.url, payload.data)
    return response.data
  } catch (e) {
    commit('notifications/PUSH_ALERT', {
      alert: e.response.data.message,
    })
  }
},
```

My API returns error which is intercepted in the Vuex action in the `catch {}` block.

Why the `.then(response)` callback is still called? Of course by response being empty.

I would expect that `.catch(error)` would be called?

Comment: you are resolving your error using catch block so it will always go to then . in order to get error in api call as well you should throw error in your catch blcok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `throw` it again like this:

```
async get({ commit }, payload) {
  try {
    let response = await this.$axios.get(payload.url, payload.data)
    return response.data
  } catch (e) {
    commit('notifications/PUSH_ALERT', {
      alert: e.response.data.message,
    })
    // Throw error again when it is handled, so outer catch can handle it too
    throw e
  }
}
```